# faraday timeout on a simple get

Tags: ruby, faraday

Is there a way to add timeout options in this simple get method?

I am using Faraday 3.3.

```
Faraday.get(url)
```

After searching around, I can only apply timeout options after I initiate a connection first, then apply timeout options. Or there's a simple way?

This is what I am doing right now:

```
conn = Faraday.new
response = conn.get do |req|
  req.url url
  req.options.timeout = 2 # 2 seconds
end
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this one:

```
conn = Faraday.new do |conn|
  conn.options.timeout = 20
end
response = conn.get(url)
```

UPD:
After I had reviewed gem sources, I found out that there's no way do it like you want.

With `get` method you can set only [url, request params and headers](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/connection.rb#L176). But to specify timeout, you have to access `@options` of `Faraday::Connection` instance. And you can do this by using `attr_reader :options`

```
conn = Faraday::Connection.new
conn.options.timeout = 20
```

Or on [initialization](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/connection.rb#L68) of Faraday::Connection instance:

```
Faraday::Connection.new(nil, request: { timeout: 20 })
```

Or when it [copies connection parameters](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/connection.rb#L387) to request parameter and [yields request back](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/connection.rb#L388):

```
Faraday::Connection.new.get(url) { |request| request.options.timeout = 20 }
```

Comment: thanks, this is similar to what I have. I was think if there's a way just pass the options in in the Faraday.get right away.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification.

Comment: There are other timeouts that can be set: I use `open_timeout` often, which is the timeout for opening the TCP connection. There's also a `read_timeout` and `write_timeout`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I ended up doing something like this so I can more easily stub the code in testing:

```rb
    def self.get(url, params: {}, headers: {}, timeout: 2)
      conn = Faraday.new(
        params: params,
        headers: headers
      ) do |conn|
        conn.options.timeout = timeout
      end

      conn.get(url)
    end
```